# Hosting rasa model in rasa_nlu server through docker

Tags: docker, rasa-nlu

I started the ***rasa_nlu*** server through ***docker*** using the command below.

```
sudo docker run -v "<path_to_projects_folder>:/app/projects" -p 5000:5000 rasa/rasa_nlu:latest-full
```

In the command prompt it show the server started as follows:

```
2018-12-12 12:26:23+0000 [-] Log opened.
2018-12-12 12:26:23+0000 [-] Site starting on 5000
2018-12-12 12:26:23+0000 [-] Starting factory <twisted.web.server.Site object at 0x7ff7a582ae10>
```

On view the status by the command below

```
curl 'http://localhost:5000/status'
```

it gave the output

```
{
"max_training_processes": 1,
"current_training_processes": 0,
 "available_projects": {
"default": {
  "status": "ready",
  "current_training_processes": 0,
  "available_models": [
    "<model_name>"
  ],
  "loaded_models": []
  }
}
}
```

But when i am sending a post request at the url by the below command

```
curl  -XPOST http://localhost:5000/parse -d '{"q":"hi"}'
```

it sends an unknown opcode error as response i.e.

```
{
  "error": "unknown opcode"
}
```

I cannot get the required output. Can anyone figure out the problem and provide me with a solution so that i can get the required response?

Comment: Can you provide us with the command you used for the POST?

Comment: What operating system are you running this on?

Comment: Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
Release: 16.04
Codename: xenial

Comment: hm, I can't reproduce, but I am on OSX. Does a GET do the same thing? `curl http://localhost:5000/parse\?q\=hi`

Comment: also, have you tried training a model yet?

Comment: I am using a trained model which has been trained offline. And the get request also gives the same error.